# The order of validation summary doesn't correspond to the order of controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form in asp.net MVC 4 application. I use data annotation attribute on my model class to validate the user input. I use @Html.ValidationSummary() to display the Validation Summary. I think jQuery displays the validation summary. The issue is that the errors listed in the validation summary are not in the same order as control in the form. I tried to rearrange the properties in my model class to reflect the order of the controls in the form. However it didn't resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I tried to rearrange the properties in my model class. However this didn't work. My model class inherits an interface and implements. Once I rearranged the order of the property in the interface, then it worked! Hope it helps someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try (Order) annotation property to order your properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order%28v=VS.100%29.aspx